# i am making a note app i want to make id´s in an loop and then i want to check the id with a onclicklistener

Tags: android, file, sdk

i am trying to make a note app.in an array i want to make id´s.
i want to check the id with an onclicklistener.
in the onclicklistener i make an Intent and an ExtraString
in this Extrastring i want to write the content from the note file i created

this is the code :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NotizOeffnungsMenue extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


Button[] NoteListBtn ;
String[] NoteList ;
int [] e;
int i;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notiz_oeffnungs_menue);

    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);




    NoteListBtn = new Button[fileList().length];
    NoteList = fileList();

    i = 0;




   while (i < fileList().length)
    {


        NoteListBtn[i] = new Button(this);
        NoteListBtn[i].setText(NoteList[i]);
        NoteListBtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);
        l1.addView(NoteListBtn[i]);
        NoteListBtn[i].setId(i);

        e [i] =i;

        i++;



    }






}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notiz_oeffnungs_menue, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{

    if(e[] == view.getId())
    {
        Intent switchintent = new Intent(this,NotizActivity.class);
        String EXTRA_INHALT;

       startActivity(switchintent);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `onClick()` I would recommend u to use `switch case` statement

```
        switch(v.getId()){
         case R.id.butnid:
           //do something here
                 break;

           case R.id.butnid2:
           //do something here
                 break;

         }
```

Make as many cases as u want.

And remember that the `buttons` u use should do this

```
         butnid.setOnClickListener(this);
         butnid2.setOnClickListener(this);
          //And so on for ever id u use in on click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent switchintent = new Intent(this,NotizActivity.class);
    switchintent.putExtra("EXTRA_INHALT", e[view.getId()]);
    switchintent.putExtra("EXTRA_INHALT2", NoteList[view.getId()]);
    startActivity(switchintent);
}
```

Instead of comparing id, you can use that as a position. Because you are already setting that position as Id.

Hope this helps.